# Free actions with Action overwriting (Custom Actions)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

Hey I have been having this situation, because of how frequent, We are going to be using custom actions in the project I´m working on, We decided to just have all custom actions using the component overwriting function.

Well the problem I'm having now is that when I want to use the isFreeAction option so It will be added to the toolbar, when I do this it renders all my custom actions to the toolbar and it only works if I also add MTableAction to the components in the Action section.

The problem here is that I don't see a way to have full control of what renders in the Toolbar because all the actions that have isFreeAction is not send in the props for the Action section is only send in the props in the Toolbad section.

Here some code:

```
Action: (props) => (
   <>
     <MTableAction {...props} />
     {props.action.tooltip === "place-holder" && (
       <>
         {/* <MTableAction {...props} /> */}
         {detalle && (
           <Tooltip
             title={
               toolTips && toolTips.detalle ? toolTips.detalle : "Detalle"
             }
             arrow
           >
             <IconButton
               aria-label="detalle"
               size="small"
               className={classes.iconButton}
               onClick={() => detalle(props)}
             >
               <Detalle />
             </IconButton>
           </Tooltip>
         )}
       </>
     )}
   </>
 ),
 Toolbar: (props) => (
   <>
     <MTableToolbar {...props} />
     {generar && (
       <BotonVerde
         className={classes.button}
         startIcon={<SettingsIcon />}
         onClick={() =>
           generar.funcion ? generar.funcion(props) : generar(props)
         }
       >
         {generar.titulo ? generar.titulo : "GENERAR"}
       </BotonVerde>
     )}
   </>
 ),
```

Props for Action:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31524850/91063031-71fa4300-e5fb-11ea-973b-3d1c05f58c0e.png

Props for Toolbar:

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/31524850/91063252-c271a080-e5fb-11ea-9b55-1a20213b744e.png

The only way arround I see right now is to make my own Toolbar component, I just think there should be a way to control the Free Actions section just like you can with the normal actions.

Any suggestions?

Am I missing something?

Have a good day.